# SSD Windows 10 crash problems

Tags: windows-10, ssd, crash

A couple of days ago my computer crashed. I tested the ram and it seemed fine. The next day the computer worked again, but it was indeed slow. I found out that the 120gig ssd with Windows10 was about 90% full. I couldn't move or delete files, so I booted Linux from a USB and removed unnecessary files. I got the SSD down to exactly 50%, and was satisfied with my accomplishment.   Sadly, that didn't make the deal. My computer is still slow, and I seem. To get errors if I try to create files. I don't know what to do, and I'm afraid I've done something stupid while removing the files with Linux. I've read that SSDs shouldn't have to be defragmented, but I said, I fear that the Linux rd command doesn't do it properly.
Do you have any clue on how I can fix this?

**EDIT:**
I just tried opening CMD and got this error:

```
C:\Windows\System32\cmd.exe
The volume does not contain a recognized file system.
Please make sure that all required file system drivers are loaded and that the volume is not corrupted.
```

Thank you for any help,
Malcolm

Comment: you should start with basic diagnostics about file integrity, corrupted / damaged files and so on. "my computer is slow how to solve it" just doesn't cut it.

Comment: Have you tried to reinstall the operating system?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

At this point, Linux may be your only and best friend... As your main windows Filesystem is not responding correctly, I would NOT trust anything you run in it to fix it, as you don't know what is wrong. As it might cause more damage to your system...

Depending on the Linux system, it is unlikely that it broke your Windows partition... Anyway, you should do a file-system check with a Linux Live USB. Most come with a tool called `gparted`.

At this point we are going to be doing something that has a possiblility to break your system... Not that it's likely, however it merits a...

***Disclamer:** While this process is unlikely to break your system, I cannot and will not be held responcible for any damages to your system created by this guide. Continue at your own risk.*

## Using GParted

Alright with that out of the way; depending on your Linux system you might have to install it, I will not include it here as installations very between systems.

If you go to your terminal, you should be able to enter `sudo gparted`. This will bring up a new window that will show at the bottom "Searching /dev/sda for partitions" as soon as that finishes take a look at the structure, make sure it is the correct sized disk, and that it is showing the correct device.

At this point you will have one to three NFTS filesystems. The largest one is most likely your Windows partition. (assuming you haven't installed another OS alongside Windows)

Simply right click the largest one and select the "Check" option from the menu. Now all you have to do is click the apply button. (Normally a green check-mark, but could be different...) Give it a few moments to execute, and you should hopefully be good to go.

## If that doesn't help

Do a quick memory test (by quick I mean let it run for about an hour). I won't post a guide on how to, as it varies based on the tools you use. I would just recommend creating a bootable USB or CD with a memory test image burned onto it.

## And if All else fails...

If the above methods doesn't work, you should try a command called `badblocks`. This command may take a few hours... so you have been warned. Again if it is not installed, you will have to look that up as you didn't specify a Linux system.

Just use the command `sudo badblocks -sv /dev/<device>` replace `<device>` with the 3 letter combination for your hard drive, and the partition number of windows. (example /dev/sda2). Make sure it is NOT mounted. As mounting it may cause inconsistencies in the program.

Hope this Helps!